# How to convert Class Component to Functional Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to convert this class based to functional component

```
class Main extends Components{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      posts:[
      {
        id:"0",
        description:"abc",
        imageLink:"https.xyz"
      },
      {
        id:"1",
      description:"abc",
      imageLink:"https.xyz"
      }
    ]
    }
  }
  render(){
    return
    <>
    <Photowall posts={this.state.posts}/>
    </>
  }
}
```

And i have done like in functional

```
posts = [
      {
        id:"0",
        description:"abc",
        imageLink:"https.xyz"
      },
      {
        id:"1",
      description:"abc",
      imageLink:"https.xyz"
      }
    ]

function Main() {
  const [post, setPost] = useState('posts');
  return (

    <>
    <Header title={"Photowall"} />
    <Photowall posts = {posts}/>
    
    
    </>
  )
}
```

first i put posts in an array then useState to this posts. I want to call the posts from this useState not from outside like as it already like.
`posts = [....]`
and then
`<Photowall post = {posts}/>`
**But error facing error**

Comment: You use the string `'posts'`, not the variable in `useState('posts')`. It should be `useState(posts)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your first example your component should look like this, with the default value of posts in the useState

```js
import React, { useState } from "react"

const Main = () => {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([
        {
            id:"0",
            description:"abc",
            imageLink:"https.xyz"
        },
        {
            id:"1",
            description:"abc",
            imageLink:"https.xyz"
        }
    ])

    return (
        <>
            <Header title={"Photowall"} />
            <Photowall posts = {posts}/>
        </>
    )
}

export default Main
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the JS engine to evaluate 'posts' by removing "" from it and it will work. Here it is:

```
posts = [
      {
        id:"0",
        description:"abc",
        imageLink:"https.xyz"
      },
      {
        id:"1",
      description:"abc",
      imageLink:"https.xyz"
      }
    ]

function Main() {
  const [post, setPost] = useState(posts);
  return (

    <>
    <Header title={"Photowall"} />
    <Photowall posts = {posts}/>
    
    
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the array inside useState, and remove global posts variable. Simple.

```js
function Main() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState(
     [
      {
        id:"0",
        description:"abc",
        imageLink:"https.xyz"
      },
      {
        id:"1",
      description:"abc",
      imageLink:"https.xyz"
      }
    ]
  );

 // rest of your code 

}
```